# How to create a "Done" soft key using jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a form where I have one search box. On tapping on that I want to display one custom "Done" soft key where on tapping on that button, my search keyword should get submitted to the server. 
Can anyone guide me on how to implement these kind of custom soft keys using jquery mobile.

Comment: what do you mean by soft key?

Comment: Agree with @Omar you need to clarify what you mean by *soft key*. An example implementation (as url) that you're trying to mimic (if any) might help to help you.